Fill ClientRegistrationRepository from application.properties
I am actually trying to create a ClientRegistrationRepository from properties located in application-test.properties
enter image description here
The problem I am facing is that I am not able to register with
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fox

and getting this error
Parameter 0 of method feignOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager in com.emobg.microservice.client.config.SecureClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

enter image description here
I have seen many samples in yaml format but I am not sure how to register it in .properties format
Thanks in advance
I have tried with
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.fox=

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.id=fox

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration=fox

But no luck
